# Get impression or hit statistics on Facebook feed posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get figures on the number of impressions, hits, or number of users that a particular Facebook post **that is not part of a Page** has been seen by?

To paraphrase, let's say that I make a post on my personal Facebook account, can I use the API (or another method) with my own access token to look up how much visibility this post has received?

The Insights APIs seem to be restricted to posts that are on a "Page", which from what I can see is distinct from a user's personal profile or feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly, post insights are available for page posts only.

There isn’t a similar thing for posts on user timelines.

(If you are sharing content from your own domain, then Domain Insights might be able to give some data.)